# Filter Non English Keywords from Python List

Tags: python, regex, list, filter

I have the below python list,

```
List= ['Images', 'Maps', 'Play', 'YouTube', 'News', 'Gmail', 'Drive', None, 
'Web History', 'Settings', 'Sign in', 'Advanced search', 'Language tools', 
'हिन्दी', 'বাংলা', 'తెలుగు', 'मराठी', 'தமிழ்', 'ગુજરાતી', 'ಕನ್ನಡ', 'മലയാളം', 
'ਪੰਜਾਬੀ', 'Advertising\xa0Programs', 'Business Solutions', '+Google', 
'About Google', 'Google.co.in', 'Privacy', 'Terms']
```

I want to filter non english keywords from this list and want my final list to look like this,

```
List=['हिन्दी', 'বাংলা', 'తెలుగు', 'मराठी', 'தமிழ்', 'ગુજરાતી', 'ಕನ್ನಡ', 'മലയാളം','ਪੰਜਾਬੀ']
```

Is this can be done with Regex? I use Python 3.x
Thanks for help!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since non-English characters are all above the 7-bit ASCII range, you can test if the ordinal numbers of any of the characters in each word are above 127 and is considered an alphabet by `str.isalpha()`:

```
[w for w in List if w and any(ord(c) > 127 and c.isalpha() for c in w)]
```

With your sample input, this returns:

`['हिन्दी', 'বাংলা', 'తెలుగు', 'मराठी', 'தமிழ்', 'ગુજરાતી', 'ಕನ್ನಡ', 'മലയാളം', 'ਪੰਜਾਬੀ']`

Comment: Nice! Really great lateral thinking here.

Comment: Some non-English words may slip through if they are European enough, eg. the Swedish word 'Öppen' (open).

Comment: @figbeam Indeed. Fixed then.

Comment: Could anyone breakdown this list comprehension?

Comment: @MasooriMenon This list comprehension does the following: for every word `w` in `List`, test if `w` is truthy (and therefore not an empty string), and if any of the character `c` in the word `w` has an ordinal number greater than 127 (because those of English characters are all below 128) and is considered an alphabet (to exclude punctuation marks and symbols). Only if all of the above are satisfied will the list comprehension output `w` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

It is also doable in regex.

```
import re

result = ["".join(re.findall("[^\u0000-\u05C0]",i)) for i in List if i is not None and re.findall("[^\u0000-\u05C0]",i)]

print (result)
```

Result:

```
['हिन्दी', 'বাংলা', 'తెలుగు', 'मराठी', 'தமிழ்', 'ગુજરાતી', 'ಕನ್ನಡ', 'മലയാളം', 'ਪੰਜਾਬੀ']
```